# NSFetchResultController to sort chat items in date (dd/mm/yyyy) sections and each section again sorted by dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am creating a chat application UI like whats app where I need to sort the chat messages and section them based on NSDate (DD/MM/YY).

Each distinct (DD/MM/YY) section names will have items sorted again on the timestamp containing this date.

How can I achieve this in NSFetchResultsController. I was successful achieving this using Distinct Query to get all the Chat Objects dates that match the DD/MM/YYYY and find section names.

Then again make a query to DB to find all chats matching the chat objects timestamp for the date portion but time as different for each.

But this consumes heavy UI / Backend operation on core data. Is there any optimal way to achieve this.

**Example:**

> **Chat Object in DB**
>   *Chat ID | Message Text | Timestamp | Sender Id | Receiver Id*
>
> **Data Example**
>   *CHAT-001 | This is test 1 message | 22/10/2015:12:00:20 | abc.dev.abc.com | def.dev.abc.com*
>   *CHAT-002 | This is test 2 message | 22/10/2015:13:00:20 | abc.dev.abc.com | def.dev.abc.com*
>   *CHAT-003 | This is test 3 message | 22/10/2015:13:10:20 | def.dev.abc.com | abc.dev.abc.com*
>   *CHAT-004 | This is test 4 message | 22/10/2015:14:10:20 | def.dev.abc.com | abc.dev.abc.com*
>   *CHAT-005 | This is test 5 message | 23/10/2015:13:00:20 | abc.dev.abc.com | def.dev.abc.com*
>   *CHAT-006 | This is test 6 message | 23/10/2015:13:05:20 | abc.dev.abc.com | def.dev.abc.com*
>   *CHAT-007 | This is test 7 message | 24/10/2015:13:10:20 | def.dev.abc.com | abc.dev.abc.com*
>   *CHAT-008 | This is test 8 message | 24/10/2015:13:10:20 | def.dev.abc.com | abc.dev.abc.com*
>
> **Output Expected**
>
> Section name : **22/10/2015**   *CHAT-001 | This is test 1 message |
>   22/10/2015:12:00:20 | abc.dev.abc.com | def.dev.abc.com*   *CHAT-002 |
>   This is test 2 message | 22/10/2015:13:00:20 | abc.dev.abc.com |
>   def.dev.abc.com*   *CHAT-003 | This is test 3 message |
>   22/10/2015:13:10:20 | def.dev.abc.com | abc.dev.abc.com*   *CHAT-004 |
>   This is test 4 message | 22/10/2015:14:10:20 | def.dev.abc.com |
>   abc.dev.abc.com*
>
> Section name : **23/10/2015**
>   *CHAT-005 | This is test 5 message | 23/10/2015:13:00:20 | abc.dev.abc.com | def.dev.abc.com*
>   *CHAT-006 | This is test 6 message | 23/10/2015:13:05:20 | abc.dev.abc.com | def.dev.abc.com*
>
> Section name : **24/10/2015**
>   *CHAT-007 | This is test 7 message | 24/10/2015:13:10:20 | def.dev.abc.com | abc.dev.abc.com*
>   *CHAT-008 | This is test 8 message | 24/10/2015:13:10:20 | def.dev.abc.com | abc.dev.abc.com*

Any quick help so I can use NSFetchResultsController and also achieve Load More option using performFetchLimit and batch size is really appreciated.

Comment: If you are using (or happy to translate) Objective-C, this [Apple example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) gives a good idea as to how to go about it.

Comment: Thanks PBASDF but I am still not able to understand this. Is there any way you can can pass an example snippet for above requirement. would be really helpful to understand. For now what i have tried is to create another column and fill the value same as timestamp column but without time. Then pass this column as sectionkeypathname for fetch results controller to section and then use timestamp column as sort descriptor. But is this an optimal solution ?

Comment: If your new column is transient, then your solution is (in essence) the method used in the Apple example I referenced.  If you are using a new persistent attribute, then your solution is slightly different, and comes with the overhead (which might be negligible) of setting the new attribute if/whenever the timestamp changes.  But it is otherwise the same solution.  Is it working OK?  If not, post what you have so far...

Comment: I fixed that and working like charm using the transient attribute, did bit of learning for Coredata transient usage... Thanks a ton for this advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that and working like charm using the transient attribute, did bit of learning for Coredata transient usage... Thanks a ton for this advices.